# Change interface to an object type

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

The below works great if I'm just passing in the props one after another

```
Example: const [] = useHook(3, 500, ref);
```

But I want to change it to an object:

```
Example: const [] = useHook({spike: 0, timeout: 500});
```

How would I write that in my interface and still keep my function return types.

```
   interface IProps {
      (spike?: number, timeout?: number, ref?: any): [
        string,
        number,
        string| null,
      ];
    }

    const useHook: IProps = (
      spike= 10,
      timeout= 500,
      ref = null,
    ) => {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface IHookArgs {
  spike?: number; 
  timeout?: number; 
  ref?: any
}

interface IProps {
      (args: IHookArgs): [
        string,
        number,
        string| null,
      ];
    }

const useHook: IProps = ({ spike = 5, timeout = 6, ref = undefined}) => {
 return ['', spike, '']
}

const [] = useHook({spike: 0, timeout: 500});
```

But I prefer to describe a function with `type` and NOT `interface`:

```
interface IHookArgs {
  spike?: number; 
  timeout?: number; 
  ref?: any
}

type HookType = (args: IHookArgs) => [string, number, string| null];

const useHook: HookType = ({ spike = 5, timeout = 6, ref = undefined}) => {
 return ['', spike, '']
}

const [] = useHook({spike: 0, timeout: 500});
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing I noticed is when I call the hook without any arguments I get this warning: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts
useHook.tsx(27, 18): An argument for 'args' was not provided. I'd like it to not warn if  none of the args are in there as they are optional and been set by default.

Comment: I already tried using the ? operator but then the args in the function error out. Property 'spike' does not exist on type 'IHookArgs | undefined'.

Comment: Any other ideas here other than args?: IHookArgs

Comment: just add the default values. Updated the answer. See if this is ok.

Comment: Unfortunately default or no default numbers it still doesn't work. So is the above code working for you ? I'm still getting the same error unless I add an empty object  to  const [] = useHook({})  which is what I'm trying to do away with.

Comment: did you try adding the default value fo object `({ spike = 5, timeout = 6, ref = undefined} = {})`. and `(args?: IHookArgs)`